# How could I rewrite a formula looking to me too much summarized/simplified?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation, article-writing

On a book, to present me a transformation required during a *Principal Component Analysis (PCA)*, with:

$\mathbf{I}$ : the set of individuals
$\mathbf{i}$ : an index going over one individual
$\mathbf{l}$ : an index going over a second individual
$\mathbf{k}$ : an index going over the variables [coming from a $K$ set not shown in the formula below]

the book tells, while explaining the process of standardizing values and the centered/reduced variables, that $d^2(i, l)$, the Euclidean distance between the individuals $i$ and $l$, shows that the variance of a $k$ variable has relationship with the formula:

$$ s^{2}_{k} = \frac{1}{2I^2}\sum\limits_{i,l}\big(x_{ik} - x_{lk}\big)^2$$

but this formula, for me, isn't pleasant to read.

- $2I^2$ uses **I**, a set, but with the underlying goal of extracting its cardinal
  So I should have seen $\mathbf{n_{I}}$ (if acceptable?) or **Card(I)** here instead, even if its long, I guess.
- $\sum\limits_{i,l}$ summarizes a double summation.

How could I write this formula more correctly?

Comment: I might write $2|I|^2$ instead of $2I^2$, but the double sum is correct. In fact the whole thing seems to me to be fine, and almost anything you do will spoil it.

Comment: What do you dislike about the double summation operator $\sum_{i,\,l}$? Would you prefer $\sum_{(i,\,l)\in I\times I}$? (The set $I\times I$ is often denoted $I^2$.) I second @ancientmathematician's suggestion to write the prefactor as $\frac{1}{2|I|^2}$.

Comment: I was mislead by $I^2$, and didn't noticed it was meaning $I \times I$ which looks more clear to me, to explain the summation coming with two indexes.
You all believe there's no trouble or a really minor one, so I'm relieved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double summation is fine.

When $I$ is finite, it is common practice to denote $|I|$ the number of elements of $I$.

Second point, I would prefer to separate the indices by a comma.

Third (minor) point. The letter $l$ is easily confused with $1$, or even with $i$ in small characters. To avoid this use $\ell$ instead (\ell in $\LaTeX$). Altogether, you could write your formula as
$$
s^{2}_{k} = \frac{1}{2|I|^2}\sum_{i,\ell}\big(x_{i,k} - x_{\ell,k}\big)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, and good idea, the $\ell$!